# C# Connect to Oracle DataBase Error ORA-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist

Tags: c#, oracle11g, database-connection

I want to connect to Oracle database from C# but I can't
Because this errors that ORA-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist
so how can i ?

**C# code**

```
  string strConn = "Data Source =(DESCRIPTION =" +
                                 "(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = DESKTOP-EIQ5MRF)(PORT = 1521))" +
                                 "(CONNECT_DATA =" +
                                 " (SERVER = DEDICATED)" +
                                 "(SERVICE_NAME = XE)" +
                                 ")" +
                                 ");User Id =system;password=bluesky;";
                OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(strConn);

                conn.Open();
                conn.Close();
```

**listener.ora**

> SID_LIST_LISTENER =   (SID_LIST =
>       (SID_DESC =
>         (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
>         (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
>         (PROGRAM = extproc)
>       )
>       (SID_DESC =
>         (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
>         (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
>         (PROGRAM = extproc)
>       )   )
>
> LISTENER =   (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
>       (DESCRIPTION =
>         (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
>         (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = DESKTOP-EIQ5MRF)(PORT = 1521))
>       )   )
>
> DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (XE)
>
> tnsnames.ora
>
> XE =   (DESCRIPTION =
>       (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = DESKTOP-EIQ5MRF)(PORT = 1521))
>       (CONNECT_DATA =
>         (SERVER = DEDICATED)
>         (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
>       )   )
>
> EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =   (DESCRIPTION =
>       (ADDRESS_LIST =
>         (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
>       )
>       (CONNECT_DATA =
>         (SID = PLSExtProc)
>         (PRESENTATION = RO)
>       )   )
>
> ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =    (DESCRIPTION = 
>       (ADDRESS_LIST = 
>         (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1)) 
>       ) 
>       (CONNECT_DATA = 
>         (SID = CLRExtProc) 
>         (PRESENTATION = RO) 
>       )    )

Comment: Check your connection string. The most likely cause is that you have made a mistake in there.

Comment: "ORA-12454: connect failed because target host or object does not exist "-check your connection string

Comment: Just a suggestion,try to replace DESKTOP-EIQ5MRF with the machine ip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error

> ORA-12454: connect failed because target host or object does not exist

It's mean you have problem with connection string, check all access data, machine name once again and try use this connection string, you forgot add "ADDRESS_LIST" , check [doc.](https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle-data-provider-for-net-odp-net/) here.

Using `ODP.NET` without `tnsnames.ora`, should be like

```
    var sampleConn= @"Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=    (PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=MyHost)(PORT=MyPort)))
                    (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=MyOracleSID)));
                     User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;"
```

So you connection string should look like

```
   string strCon =@"Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=DESKTOP-EIQ5MRF)(PORT=1521)))
                             (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=XE)));
                             User Id = system; Password = bluesky; ";
```