# ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified Enterprise Library

Tags: vb.net, oracle, enterprise-library, odac

Please help me, i have this error on instance the database of old project to compile, already install ODAC and Enterprise Library, but not found tnsnames.ora and dont know how to configure.

```
   Dim db = EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current.GetInstance(Of EntLibData.Database)()
    ds = db.ExecuteDataSet("IDV_AUTH.IDV_TRAER_USU", user.ToUpper)
```

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that ODAC is installed and not found tnsnames.ora.

If ODAC is installed properly you are aware of $ORACLE_HOME location, you can create tnsnames.ora file as in the following directory location:
$ORACLE_HOME\network\admin\tnsnames.ora

Also, you can consider following sample script for the content of tnsnames.ora. Where, ORCL is the identifier, Host refers the IP address in which you have Oracle Database, Port is the port number in which listener listening in the Oracle database server, and Service Name which refers the service name(similar to SID). Please, put SID = ORC if you have not configured Service Name in the database server.

```
ORC =
 (DESCRIPTION = 
   (ADDRESS_LIST =
     (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.1.0)(PORT = 1521))
   )
 (CONNECT_DATA =
   (SERVICE_NAME = ORCL)
 )
)
```

Also, you can verify by `tnsping ORC` and it should resolve the connection description.

In addition, read "Connection Strings and Objects" section in the [link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dotnet/vs2010-oracle-dev-410461.html) for further reference to use ORC in your .Net(VB/C#) code.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but how to reference the key "ORC" in my code for reference to tnsnames.ora

Comment: @SantiagoVictorinoC - See additional note at the end of reply for getting the reference how to use in your code.

Comment: Likewise, you also can refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40717481/c-sharp-connect-to-oracle-database-error-ora-12545-connect-failed-because-targe?rq=1